# Are there problems with estimating regressions of longitudinal data by year?

Tags: panel-data, probit, tobit-regression

I am studying the behavior of 900 firms for a period of 10 years. The data is a balanced panel. Multivariate analysis consists of Tobit estimations for each year and probit estimations for each year. The dependent variable is the percent of stock repurchased for a firm within a year, so it is censored at 0. The probit estimations model the probability of a firm repurchasing stock during the year. The years are important because I want to demonstrate how firms react at times when stock prices are low and when they are high. One of the independent variables of interest is a binary variable that, for many firms, does not change over the time period. As a result, firm fixed effects aren't useful because of the lack of variability of the independent variable over the 10 year period.

The relationship between the dependent variable and the binary variable should change based on the year and my preliminary results demonstrate this.

I haven't been able to find an example of this approach to determine what problems might arise.  Any guidance that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't call a lower bound here of 0 censored. It's just the lower bound. It's not that values lower than 0 are possible but not observed; they are impossible. See e.g. Baum http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0147

Comment: Nick, thank you for the link. In this instance, values lower than 0 are possible. The literature on stock repurchases uses the value of net repurchases = stock repurchases less stock issuances.  For many observations, the value of net repurchases is a negative number. The existing literature also set the value of net repurchases at 0 if the value is negative.